# How to deal with "Gmail Technical Support Telephone Number" etc

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Recently, we seem to be getting a lot of posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629437/gmail-technical-support-number-1-855-227-3084-for-password-issues-gmail-cust). Other variants have subtly different text, or might refer to outlook etc.

What is the correct way to deal with these. Should they be flagged as spam? For Moderator attention? Downvote to oblivion?

Is is possible to catch these at the submission stage instead, so we dont see them?

Comment: Not just gmail; hotmail as well :-)!

Comment: @Ben And yahoo, and lexmark, and almost everything else.

Comment: @bluefeet *Lexmark*? They're still a thing? Next we'll be getting tech support numbers for Iomega.

Comment: @vcsjones If it claims to fix click of death, i will phone it :-)

Comment: @vcsjones [Yes, lexmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415861/1-855-709-2847-lexmark-printer-helpline-number-lexmark-printer)

Comment: At least the question wasn't: "Can anyone to plz help Netscape Navigator support line?"

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Flag as spam. This is the quickest way of dealing with them. Spam flags go to a separate queue for moderators to deal with immediately, and six spam flags from the community will delete the post automatically, without a moderator even needing to intervene.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise there was auto-delete based on spam flags. I will do that in future then.

Comment: I saw around 5-6 posts like this today. flagged as blatantly off topic... will use spam flag from next time.

Answer (score 40):

Unfortunately, those are spam and yes, we receive a lot of it.  If you see it, then flag it as spam.

The accounts will be handled appropriately and the spam protection will start to kick in to slow it down.

And trust me when I say that SE is blocking a lot more than we actually see.

Comment: I assumed that almost all is probably blocked before we even see it, but I have noticed that we seem to get flurries of almost exact replicas of this.

Comment: @mjs Spammers are tricksters so some get through the filters.

Comment: 60 odd characters repeat 20 odd times could _probably_ be caught though.... Having said that I have no idea what I am actually talking about :-)

Comment: And I should point out that SE isn't the only place being hit by these people: https://www.google.com/search?q=1-844-780-6751 , but it appears to be one of the few sites that's actually cleaning up after this spam.

Comment: It seems most of the stack exchange sites are being targeted, i'd call for a mass deletion.

Comment: @Wyatt Deletion happens as soon as these get posted. Do you see any   posts of this kind surviving for more than a few minutes?

Comment: @FamousBlueRaincoat I didn't look into every post, but there were around 120 of them on SE sites when I googled.

Comment: @Wyatt: usually the results are a bit stale, click on them and you'll find they've been removed already.