# Should there be an auto-spam-catching algorithm for this type of spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

It's already been removed, but if you can see removed questions, it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333417/contact-1-855-709-2847-kodak-printer-tech-support-kodak-printer-tech-suppor). If you can't, it looks like this, only with real companies and phone numbers that I don't want to give any help to their spamming efforts, so I've removed them:

`CONTACT :1-111-111-1111 Innotech printer tech support , Innotech printer tech support number, Innotech printer tech support phone number`

Then all of that junk repeated about a jillion times, with no other text. I've personally seen these type of "questions" posted several times a day for the past several days. It seems like it'd be pretty easy to autoban questions that were literally the same junk copy-pasted dozens of times with nothing else? I know they disappear within seconds anyway, but why let them post that crap at all, and waste the mods' time cleaning it up? Spam in general is crazy difficult to detect programmatically (I'm a mod on another site, I know this well), but that *specific* spam doesn't seem like it would be?

Comment: Spam flags feed into an algorithm that blocks spam posts. So, already a thing. :) This one just didn't fit what the algorithm already has figured out as spam, so it got through. This is why it's important to flag spam as spam and not edit it out or close for any other reason. _"...and waste the mods' time cleaning it up?"_ Six spam flags automatically deletes the post, so mods don't always have to step in here. That's usually why it disappears so quickly- That or a mod sees it when it's posted.

Comment: @Kendra Ah, nice, that's good to know. So it only wastes our own time flagging it (not snarky, I'd rather waste a couple seconds of 6 regular users' time than a mod's time. Neat it works like that.)

Comment: Seen spam like that yesterday as well... Somebody testing a bot?

Comment: @Will such spam is very common and has been for a while. It's not a recent trend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to ban any particular template of spam post that you see.  It's extraordinary hard to cover the *general case* of all spam content.

There *are* a lot of spam filters in place already, and they *do* block a *huge* amount of content that never actually gets seen by humans.  Sadly, spammers have huge financial incentives to spend considerable time and effort subverting those spam filters, and the spam filters can't be *too* aggressive without risking a large false positive rate.

To try to deal with these problems SO works to combine entirely automated mechanisms for preventing spam with lots of manual methods or hybrid methods, such as cases where the automated mechanisms learn from content marked as spam manually, to better identify it in the future, or cases where posts are marked as probable spam for a human user to verify the validity of (sadly, some reviewers will actually approve this blatant spam, which is another problem that has to be dealt with).

Comment: To support the _"do block a huge amount of content"_ statement, [this answer from Tim posted in February](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286615) gives a nice indication of how well the spam filters are working across the network, or at least how they did over a year.

Comment: Will the learning mechanism successfully learn even in the case where the "spam" doesn't actually contain any links, just a phone number? (Presumably for SEO purposes.) If so, I suppose that's good enough, and we should hopefully stop seeing this crap soon enough. Thanks.

Comment: @neminem For obvious reasons, the specifics of how it works aren't publicly available, but I would assume so given the limited high level descriptions of the functionality, yes.

Comment: @neminem - In addition to the above, I should point out that these particular spammers have been attacking the site for months. They've come at us from all around the world, and have been changing their spam in subtle ways to try to work around anything we do to stop it. The Tavern has a machine-learning bot that they've been training on this, but even that has missed a bunch of these as they've come in. We've usually been able to destroy the posts and accounts within minutes.

Comment: In addition to Brad's comment [see the Smoke Detector reports here](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=phone%20number&Room=89&User=266345&page=1&pagesize=50&sort=newest)

Comment: @BradLarson - regarding this particular case, have you guys ever heard from this group of spammers *why* they're doing this?  Like, did someone offend them, or are they just that bored and persistent?  It's not like they're spamming a product, they're just being obnoxious... I get the reason behind product spam, but this kind of spam is just stupid.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Spammers won't necessarily include actual references to the product(s) they intend to spam when doing test to attempt to subvert anti-spam mechanisms.  Once they determine the best way(s) to subvert the system they'll start referencing the content that they've been paid to advertise.  This is a common practice of spammers in general, and you can see it all over the place.  They're virtually certainly being paid by *someone*; people don't really spam for fun much.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Pretty sure they're just here for the promotional spam. If you look up the phone numbers they're spamming, you'll find them all over the web: https://www.google.com/search?q=1-844-780-6762&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 . Stack Exchange is one of the few places their spam doesn't stick. They sure are determined, though, and appear to be armed with a very large botnet. I don't think we're being targeted specifically.

Comment: @BradLarson - ahh, I just kind of assumed they were someone bored or off their meds and targeting Stack Overflow.  I'm so used to seeing websites spammed that I never stopped to think that someone would spam a *phone number*.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables That's what I meant about SEO - I assume the goal of it is that if you do a search for one of the terms they're spamming, they would like that phone number to be at the top of the results, because the term would thus show up next to the phone number all over the internet, at various legitimate places (that they've spammed). Pretty insidious, really.

Comment: @neminem - Thing is, it's showing up on so many sites you have to go down several Google results pages to find *their* site: http://www.printerhelplinenumber.com/ I can't imagine many people thinking that this is a reputable company just because their phone number shows up in Google and Wattpad comments.